# how compile Visual c++ project programmatically from c#?

Tags: c#, c++, build

I want to load and build my c++ project programmatically like below that  I have  built one c# project but I don't  know how to do it with my c++ project. I load c++ project and build with  no errors but in bin folder I don't see any thing

```
Microsoft.Build. Evaluation.Project p=new Project("projectname");
p.Build ();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded c++ project from somewhere and didn't checked out of output folder and working directory of project. when I was built c++ project from my c# application the exe file has been copyed in working directory but I thinked that it must be in output directory. my c sharp application is working!